# PHP : How to make parallel arrays from multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type of array

```
$arr = array( 
   0 => array(
         0 => array(
             'name' => 'test1',
             'country' => 'abc'  
         )
         1 => array(
             'name' => 'test2',
             'country' => 'xyz'  
         )
   )
   1 => array(
     'name' => 'test3',
     'country' => 'pqr'
   )
);
```

How can I make all arrays as parallel arrays. So that all sub arrays are parallel to each other without using any loop.
Like this

```
$arr = array( 
       0 => array(
                 'name' => 'test1',
                 'country' => 'abc'  
             )
       1 => array(
                 'name' => 'test2',
                 'country' => 'xyz'  
             )
       2 => array(
                 'name' => 'test3',
                 'country' => 'pqr'
       )
    );
```

Any help is much appreciated. !

Comment: using a loop it's easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic version of Nigel's code would be to loop the array and merge each subarray.

```
$new = [];
foreach($arr as $subarr){
    $new = array_merge($new, $subarr);
}
var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/np2ZD

Answer (score 0):

You could simply merge the arrays...

```
$out = array_merge($arr[0], [$arr[1]]);
print_r($out);
```

Which gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [country] => abc
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [country] => xyz
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => test3
            [country] => pqr
        )

)
```